# Cannot setup Jackal Clearpath's network

Tags: ros, jackal, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot setup Jackal's network by connecting to my machine via a network cable. When I try to ssh to jackal as mention in this link https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/jackal/network.html I get an error message saying no route to host.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296883/cannot-setup-jackal-clearpath%27s-network/) by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2018-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-07-11**:
are you using a ethernet cable to connect?

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-07-11**:
I guess that your problem is that  when you try to ssh into the Jackal using the default IP (ssh administrator@192.168.1.11) you are getting that error right?

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-07-11**:
Yes I am using an ethernet cable, and I do get that error when I try to ssh when using the default IP. I'm not sure if it's something wrong with my laptop's ethernet driver or something wrong with the jackal

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-07-11**:
Also, I am on a class C network with network number 192.168.94 so the static IP that the tutorial tells me to give my computer (192.168.1) cannot be achieved if I'm not mistaken. Sorry, I'm very new to Jackal and also don't know much about networks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try giving the static IP? You can try this:

In the right side of the top bar click the connection menu and select **Edit connections**.
Choose the wired connection and click **Edit**, then choose the  **IPv4Settings** tab and change the Method to **Manual**. There you can add an IP like 192.168.1.50 by clicking the **Add** button.
Then you should be able to ssh using the default static IP:

```
ssh administrator@192.168.1.11
```

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-07-11**:
what should I put for the net mask and gateway when I am editing the wired connection?

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-07-11**:
Leave them empty for now and give it a try

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-07-11**:
This has worked, thank you so much!

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-07-11**:
I am glad it helped. You can accept the answer as correct now :)